# Which GUI library to use with Deep Learning

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have completed basics Deep Learning course from coursera using Tensorflow and Keras.
Now I want to apply GUI to it.
So which library should i learn:
1.PyQt
2.Kivy
3.Tkinter
Are there libraries which can help to easily create deep learning projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how far you want to go.

If you are very serious about GUI apps, PyQt is the only way to go.

Qt5 is the gold standard for cross-platform GUI right now.

But, for basic applications, you are good to go with Tkinter.

I have never used Kivy, and I don't know many people who use it.

Comment: If i learned PyQt ,will it be used in future in the field of deep learning.Or I will waste my time doing it?

Comment: @ShivVratPandey , I meant how serious you are about GUI apps. I know a lot of people in DL field who never made even one GUI app in their entire career.

Comment: thank you and sorry i didnt meant to be rude.